# Insertion of "y" sound between vowels

Tags: pronunciation

I was watching some anime today, and I heard "y" sounds in places I didn't expect.

Here's a [sound clip (MP3)](http://sandwich.quarplet.com/y.mp3) and my transcription:

> 私の世界へようこそ。
>   今やこの世界をコントロールできる唯一の人間だ。

There are two "y" sounds I didn't expect.  I'm not sure whether they're related.

1. `世界へ` sounds like "sekai ye" rather than "sekai e".
2. `世界を` sounds like "sekai yo" rather than "sekai (w)o".

Can anyone explain these "y" sounds to me?  Are they standard?  Common?

Comment: That kind of phenomena occurs in English and other languages: http://web2.uvcs.uvic.ca/courses/elc/sample/listeninga/u1/1_2_1l5.htm

Comment: Since it appeared to be unrelated, I moved example #3 (`今や`) into a separate question: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9522/understanding-the-particle-%E3%82%84-in-the-phrase-%E4%BB%8A%E3%82%84

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In cases 1 and 2, you have two vowels in succession: /ie/ and /io/.

Assuming that

1. Your articulatory organs cannot jump from one discrete state to another.
2. You do not generally stop/weaken your breath between words/morae (of course once in a while you have to stop to breathe in)

you will hear the mouth/tongue moving from i->e and i->o, which is what makes it sound like "ye" and "yo".

For the same reason, I would say that you can't really tell if it's おみやげ or おみあげ, unless you know, or you ask somebody to articulate clearly, thereby probably breaking assumption 2 above.

Comment: Accurate answer, but it could be made easier to understand. I think the problem simply comes from the fact that an English speaker would expect to find a glottal stop before a word starting with e and o (which, phonetically, is not wo, but o), but since there is no glottal stop in Japanese, and since particles effectively form part of the word they are attached to, this run-in of sounds confused him.

Comment: @alexandrec: To be honest, I find your answer harder to understand - not least because I wouldn't expect to find a glottal stop before words starting with e and o in English. I'm not sure I know of a dialect that reliably does that, and it mostly comes down to how careful the speaker is.

Comment: @alexandrec, glottal stop does occur in Japanese (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_phonology#Glottal_stop_insertion) but as you wrote, (usually) not between particles and what they attach to.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out 今や is actually a set phrase and can mean "presently, currently." As opposed to 今, I believe it is used more for past contrast.

For the "y" sounds you hear during dialogue, I'd like to believe it's more of a case of individual distinction in how they speak or possibly a case of slurring(?).

Comment: Since it appeared to be unrelated, I moved example #3 (`今や`) into a separate question: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9522/understanding-the-particle-%E3%82%84-in-the-phrase-%E4%BB%8A%E3%82%84