# Understanding the particle や in the phrase "今や"

Tags: set-phrases

(Moved from [Insertion of "y" sound between vowels](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9519/insertion-of-y-sound-between-vowels) since it appeared to be unrelated.)

In the following quote:

> 私の世界へようこそ。 **今や**この世界をコントロールできる唯一の人間だ。

What is the function of the particle `や` here?  I see a definition for `今や` in [edict](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E4%BB%8A%E3%82%84&eng=&dict=edict):

> now (esp. in contrast to the past); now at last; at present; right now

I don't understand how `や` figures into this, though.  I would have expected `今は`.  Is there any way to understand the function of `や` here, or should I memorize `今や` as a set phrase?

Comment: I think や in Classical Japanese sometimes works very like contrastive/emphasizing-wa in modern Japanese. Coincidentally, 也 in Classical Chinese has a similar function. I don't know if they are related or not. 「回**や**その楽しみを改めず」「中庸の徳**たるや**其れ至れるかな」『論語』

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Goo](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/14978/m1u/%E4%BB%8A%E3%82%84/) lists this や as being a 強意の間投助詞, i.e. an interjectory particle used for emphasis.

That would be definition 4-2 [here](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/220994/m1u/%E3%82%84/), where it also mentions またもや

I don't think this や is really productive anymore, so I would memorize 今や as a word/an expression by itself.